# How to build my own "common word" filter with Lucene

Tags: java, search-engine, lucene

I know that Lucene uses a *stop word*(common) filter for searching and I also know that for this job the *Standard Analyzer* or *EnglishAnalyzer* are responsible. What about, if I want to add my own common words to the analyzer filter? How could I add words like computer, internet, system, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "common words" you mean *stopwords*.

In order to add to standard list, just use another constructor of `StandardAnalyzer` (which accepts stopwords either as `CharArraySet` or `Reader`). To get standard stopword set, use `StopAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. That's what i was talking about.